# Magento not importing all products

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, import

I try to run an import with about 9000 products in it. When I run it it only creates 250 products

**PHP.ini**

```
; This file is for CGI/FastCGI installations.
; Try copying it to php5.ini, if it doesn't work

; adjust memory limit

memory_limit = 64M

max_execution_time = 18000

; disable magic quotes for php request vars

magic_quotes_gpc = off

; disable automatic session start
; before autoload was initialized

flag session.auto_start = off

; enable resulting html compression

zlib.output_compression = on

; disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

suhosin.session.cryptua = off

; turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = off

; PHP for some reason ignores this setting in system php.ini 
; and disables mcrypt if this line is missing in local php.ini

extension=mcrypt.so

; Disable PHP errors, notices and warnings output in production mode to    prevent exposing sensitive information.

display_errors = Off
```

**Import script**

```
include_once "../app/Mage.php";
include_once "../downloader/Maged/Controller.php";

Mage::init();

// Set the store id
$app = Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

if(($handle = fopen("simple.csv", "r")) !== FALSE){
fgetcsv($handle);
while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE){
  try{
    $Simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $Simpleproduct
      ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
      ->setAttributeSetId(4)
      ->setTypeId('simple')
      ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
      ->setName($data[4])
      ->setWeight(4.0000)
      ->setStatus(1) //(1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
      ->setTaxClassId(2) //(0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
      ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)
      ->setPrice($data[3]);

     if($Simpleproduct->save()){
        echo "product ".$sku." Was created<br>";
        $row++;
     }
  }catch(Exception $e){
    die();
    echo "<p><b>";
    echo $e;
    echo "</p></b><br>";
    echo $data[4];
  }
  }
}else{
    echo "Handle == false";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your script but buy the looks of things, you are programmatically creating the product just fine.

But i do see something which may stop the script from completing and im just going to throw it out there just for keep sake.

In you while loop, you have a try / catch and what i think is happening is that your script will loop through each row before it throws an exception. When it does throw an exception, it dies and the script exits which means it will not continue.

What i suggest is to probably remove `die();` and replace it with `Mage::log($e->getMessage());` and remove the echo's underneath it too.

Once thats done, make sure Magento logging is turned on and just for peice of mind set `display_errors = On`

Clear cache and run it again, then let us know of the output.

Comment: I've applied the changes you suggested but the script still stops executing after about 250. There is no message displayed and even after enableling error logging there are no error logs to be found..

Comment: Ok add a link to the csv, so i cant test your script. Then i can see whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem was the `php.ini` file. I've created my own and places it on te server but it wasn't working. When I checked the location of the file with `phpinfo();` I discovered there was a `php.ini` file on the server on a place not accessible for users. I created a `.user.ini` file to extend the `max_execution_time` but still no success. Eventually I split my file in serveral smaller ones to import the products